# hadoop 2.2.0 job -list throws NPE

Tags: hadoop

I compiled hadoop 2.2.0 x64 and running it on a cluster. When I do `hadoop job -list` or `hadoop job -list all`, it throws a NPE like this:

```
14/01/28 17:18:39 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
14/01/28 17:18:39 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.tools.CLI.listJobs(CLI.java:504)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.tools.CLI.run(CLI.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.main(JobClient.java:1237)
```

and on hadoop webapp like jobhistory ( I turn on the jobhistory server). it shows no job was running and no job finishing although I was running jobs.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when trying to migrate to mapreduce over to YARN.  Turns out I was missing the directive in `mapred-site.xml` instructing map reduce to use YARN:

```
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```